# Change points labels in chartJS and Flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask, chart.js

I want to change labels in a chart created in ChartJS in a Flask application. Namely:

1. I render template and pass object **results_lc** with 3 attributes: **date**, **points** and **time**.
2. Using chartJS I have created chart where on X axis I have **dates** (labels) and on Y axis I have **points**.
3. Now my problem is that particular points labels are also **points**, but instead of them I want to have **times**.

Below is my code:

```
            <script>
                const allTimes = [
                    {% for result in results_lc %}
                    '{{ result.swimtime }}',
                    {% endfor %}];

                var ctx = document.getElementById("myAreaChart");
                var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                  type: 'line',
                  data: {
                    labels:
                    [{% for result in results_lc %}
                        '{{ result.date }}',
                    {% endfor %}],
                    datasets: [{
                      label: "FINA points",
                      lineTension: 0.3,
                      backgroundColor: "rgba(192,0,0,0.2)",
                      borderColor: "rgba(192,0,0,1)",
                      pointRadius: 5,
                      fill: true,
                      pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(192,0,0,1)",
                      pointBorderColor: "rgba(255,255,255,0.8)",
                      pointHoverRadius: 5,
                      pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(192,0,0,1)",
                      pointHitRadius: 50,
                      pointBorderWidth: 2,
                      data: [
                      {% for result in results_sc %}
                        {{ result.fina_points }},
                    {% endfor %}],
                    }],
                  },
                  options: {
                    plugins: {
                      legend: {
                        display: false
                      },
                      tooltips: {
                        callbacks: {
                          label: context => "swimtime: " + allTimes[context.dataIndex]
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                });
            </script>
```

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Here instead of FINA points: 612 I want to have: swimtime: 00:52,80.

Either FINA points and swimtime are passed in the list of dictionaries to the template.

I have tried different approaches but none of them worked :<

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand where your issue is coming from ... is the data in your python array not OK, or the data is OK but the result is mangled. I take it that points is a numeric value - are there numeric values on the x axis instead of dates? Can you please give an example on a concrete issue case - either with data or by an image?

Comment: @kikon I have edited post and attached an image what is my problem :)

Comment: Now it's clear. Please let me know if my answer works, or needs some correction - I have tested only the javascript, but not the jinja part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have indicated you wanted to change is the [tooltip](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#tooltip). It can be configured in many ways, as you can see from the docs.

But first you have to send the `times` from python to the script. One way to do that is to just declare a new variable, at the beginning of your script, following your approach for the other two components (I suppose this is not user data and you trust it):

```js
const allTimes = [
    {% for result in results_lc %}
    '{{ result.time }}',
    {% endfor %}];
```

Then you continue the script as before, with `var ctx = ...`,
but add in the chart configuration under `plugins` the configuration for the tooltip with a custom [`label` callback](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#label-callback):

```js
    plugins: {
        legend: {
            display: false,
        },
        tooltip: {
            callbacks: {
                label: context => "swimtime: " + allTimes[context.dataIndex]
            }
        }
    }
```

That should do it.

Comment: Hi,

It is still now working and displaying points instead of times :(

I post the code in the question body.

Comment: Aaaaa OK it is working !!!!

Comment: Thanks @kikon a lot ! It was mistake on my side, instead of "tooltip" I had "tooltips". Now it is working exactly in the way I want, you're great !

Answer (score 0):

In new Chart you have a prop called datasets.label: FINA points. Change this to respective label that you want.